# redirect or point an IP to another server

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ip

I'm not sure if this question should be ask here because it is coding related, so if I post in the wrong place please suggest me where should I post.

I recently move my server that I use to host in Thailand to Godaddy and I've moved everything except my webboard (forum) and the url it used to be it is http://mydomainname.com/forum now that forum doesn't exist in the new server with godaddy, but it does exist in the directory call `forum` in the old server. I don't want to make a load to my Godaddy server and thought if I can still host them in the Thai server, but without having to change the old URL.

With sub domain I think I know the way how to do it, but I don't know how to do this by poiting to another server but with child directory.

I'm not sure if my question is confusing, but what I'm trying to ask is how can I point to another server to to have my forum work on my http://mydomainname.com/forum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask you new server to act like a proxy for the old server by adding something like this in the new server htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^forum(/.*)?$ http://your.old.server.ip/forum$1 [L,P]
```

Comment: Will work only if there is only one site with forum on your.old.server.ip

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical question while moving the site from one server to another server.

The simple answer is DNS records. You will have to change the name server details and make it point to the desired ip you want. This way, your URL will point to the new IP. You can host the site anywhere you want.